# how to check column data is not there in table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i need to check product is in table or not

if not in table i need to assign productId for product and insert it so i tried below code ....its running successfully not inserting values...

my code

```
create proc spr_tbl_ProductNameId_insert

@productName VARCHAR(30)

as

DECLARE @key VARCHAR(5), @i int,@name varchar(30)


SET @i = 1
SET @name = (select [Product Name]  from tbl_ProductNameId where [Product Name] =@productName)

WHILE @i > 0

BEGIN

SET @key = (SELECT ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 467) + 1000)
SET @i = (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_ProductNameId WHERE [Product Id] = @key)

if(@name !=@productName)
insert into tbl_ProductNameId ([Product Name],[Product Id]) values (@productName,@key) 

end
```

where i made error...thanks

Comment: Can there be 2 product with the same name? If so, @name should be replaced by temp. table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your code, it seems you are going undefined loop, because you set `While @i > 0`

and you set the `i` value as unique random number. So never end while loop.

I done some changes with comment. please check

```
create proc spr_tbl_ProductNameId_insert

@productName VARCHAR(30)

as
BEGIN  --start always with begin end keyword
    DECLARE @key VARCHAR(5), @i int,@name varchar(30)

    SET @i = 1
    SET @name = (select [Product Name]  from tbl_ProductNameId where [Product Name] =@productName)

    WHILE @i > 0

    BEGIN

        SET @key = (SELECT ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 467) + 1000)

        --always give isnull function for default value, it good to set when result is null 
        SET @i = isnull( (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_ProductNameId WHERE [Product Id] = @key),0) 

        if(@name !=@productName)
        insert into tbl_ProductNameId ([Product Name],[Product Id]) values (@productName,@key) 

    END

END --end always with end keyword
```